# How to provide --include-path to PyCharm's less compiler?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, pycharm

I have Bootstrap sources in a common location and want to import them in my project's less file:

```
@import "bootstrap.less"
```

from the command line I would use

```
lessc --include-path="%EXT_FOLDER%/bootstrap3src" <myfile.less>
```

with grunt I would set `options.paths`. Is there any way to do this with PyCharm's bundled less plugin?  If not are there any other less plugins that can do this?

I'm using PyCharm 3.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand right, you can try File Watcher for compile less files:
http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/using-file-watchers.html

settings for file watcher look  like: http://joxi.ru/8RKqUv3JTJCaIYFP6OQ

Comment: Thanks. That got me on the right path (I ended up making a File Watcher that calls grunt upon save..)

Comment: That image link isn't working. Can you post the image directly?